Setting Mozilla Thunderbird's image (PNG) file handler on Windows 11
I installed Thunderbird on Windows 10 in 2019, but since then, it started wasting computational resources when idle and I resorted to creating a new profile a few months ago hoping to solve these performance issues. I am now on Windows 11 which changed a bit since Windows 10.
PNG files are no longer associated with any program. My Thunderbird 115.15.0 does not offer to associate with a large number of options, but most are terrible (LibreOffice Draw, Adobe Acrobat) and some even worse (Thunderbird, Wordpad). Thunderbird used to offer a cryptic option called TWINUI which would handle images in a sensible program, but it is no longer offered here. Meanwhile, Windows 11 has migrated to Microsoft Photos, which replaced Windows Photo Viewer, but apparently cannot be launched from any application anymore since it cannot be called from a stable path such as C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe.
So:

Is it normal that TWINUI is no longer offered?
Is there no way to set a more sensible PNG handler than Microsoft Paint without installing additional software or going to lengths as great as hacking the Windows registry?
If the answer to #2 is negative, am I doing something wrong or missing something here? I've been using Thunderbird on Windows for 20 years and have never seen it that bad. Is this Microsoft subtly using a monopolistic position to discourage third-party developers? Are we going backwards or is this an unintentional regression?


Windows 11 allows like all versions of Windows the user to select the executable to associate with a file extension. Windows Photo Viewer still exists on Windows 11. The workaround that works on Windows 10 to select it still works on Windows 11

As @Ramhound states, in Explorer, select any .PNG file. Right click, and select Open with >  Choose another app.  Check the box to always use the app you select, and pick one --- any one. IrfanView, Photo Viewer, Adobe Acrobat...

This solution for Photo Viewer still works.

@DrMoishePippik PNG files are already associated with Photos, but Mozilla products have their own associations. Thanks anyway

@Ramhound thanks but this question is about the Thunderbird mail user agent, a cross-platform product from Mozilla. Using a deprecated application is not my ideal solution anyway.

Well you said it can’t be used, but it can be used, so I thought you wanted to use it.

@Ramhound the fragment you seem to misinterpret refers to Microsoft Photos, not to Windows Photo Viewer.

Apart from linking an extension to an application on Windows, you can also associate an application with a file type in Thunderbird.
Look for Files & Attachments in Settings

The application you want to use, must already be associated with that file type in Windows.

You might be right, but Thunderbird only allows to change the action. Content types cannot be added, and PNG files are not in the list.
